# VBA find and mark with color

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a large data file where on a monthly basis I have to check for any errors. I'm wanting to write a macro that allows for the following:

1. IF row G does not contain the value from E
2. OR row G does not contain the value from F
3. OR row G does not contain "@email.com"
4. Then change the cell color to purple

To clarify: E contains FirstName, F contains LastName, G contains emailadress with firstname.lastname@email.com. I'm looking for errors in the emailadress, where it may have been misspelled or the wrong format was used.

I'm not allowed to make permanent changes with formulas, therefore I'm looking for a macro that will let me change the colors and an IF ELSE that allows me to turn off the color afterwards.

What would be the best way to write this in VBA?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not using conditional formatting?

Comment: I was thinking that too, but it won't allow me to add does not contain + specific text + selection of a whole row. It works for point 3, of course, but the other points won't work like that

Comment: Should be possible via formula, using `VLookup` or `CountIF` and  combining the checks with `OR`.

Comment: Mmmh. Checking a row, isn't that a taks for `HLookup()`? Oh, I see: the question mentions "row G", should that be "column G" or "row 7"? :-)

Comment: @both - I'm not allowed to permanently edit the file with formulas, therefore I was hoping to use a macro with an 'on/off' option where I can get the selection to find errors, and then remove the purple color when done.

Although the formulas and conditional formatting would do the job of finding the errors, I would have to go back afterwards to remove my formulas again.

Comment: @Dominique I've added clarification in my original post

Answer (score 0):

Select the email cells (ColG; in this example starting at G2) and add a formula-based Conditional Formatting rule using the formula:

```
=G2<>E2 & "." & F2 & "@email.com"
```

Make sure you use relative addresses in the formula (no $) - that way it will adjust for the other cells in the selected range in Col G.